# Do Russian infer the first conjugation from the verb like in Latin and Italians do?

Tags: вид

In [Latin](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/latin/stage-1-latin/lessons/lesson-1/) one does not need to have seperate words for I, you, we, she/he ect it is just inferred by the ending of the first conjugation verbs and the context.  Say for example in *I give* or *you give* ect you just change the ending for example *do* *das* respectively.

If you learn Italian you might have to learn that *I give* is *io do* but people just leave off the unnecessary *io* just as Latins would have done in some circumstances verbally.

My question is does Russian work the same? Do people just leave the redundant I, you, we, she/he ect when they speak just like Italians do and infer the first conjugation from the verb endings?

Comment: I see very interesting but it would be nice if the  I, you, we, she/he ect was routinely dropped in Russian like it is in Latin or Italian or routinely kept as either way it would make it easier to learn.

Comment: I still don't see how that particular question + answers provided not answer this exactly question. The answer is - there's no one-to-one correspondence and the usage of the pronouns differs. Compared to Latin or Italian ;)

Comment: I did not say it did not answer it particularly Constantine Geist's answer which seems to suggest you could drop the  I, you, we, she/he ect colloquially.  That question + answers that you linked is what I wanted to know.

Comment: oh, I apologize,  I got it completely wrong - I though you are requesting to reopen the question (which is a completely normal thing to do btw)

Comment: Yes, this is possible. For example, it is quite common to answer «Знаю» (I know) or «Вижу» (I see) or «Хочу» (I want) without a pronoun.

Comment: @Sergey Kirienko thanks for the examples.